# Different threads as server and client in same application

Tags: python, multithreading, client

Is it possible to make a thread server, and another client in one application. The end result will be a binary that will use one thread as server and another as client. This means two different threads will be using same port, is this possible?

I'll be using python for writing this app.

Comment: Actually it means the server thread will be listening on port X and the client thread will be using a different outgoing port to connect to localhost:X.  Why do you want to do this rather than use an in-memory queue to pass data between the threads?

Comment: @Jim: I'm guessing that it would be configurable whether the server is in or out of the process.

Comment: @Jim : Yes, this is my plan. I'm writing a pathfinding visualizer, that requires running multiple algorithms simultaneously (one algo per thread). Server thread will create one slave thread per request, that will do calculations and send it to GUI thread. I'm doing this so that I can use "asynchant.py". This will make things really simple, and I wont have to worry about locking objects etc.

Comment: You'll have to worry about overrunning the OS's socket buffers, which could lead to deadlock or data loss unless you've programmed for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; if you're listening on a port in one thread, you can connect to it on a different thread in the same process.

In Python, this would be achieved using [the `threading` module](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html).